# Guice and MVP pattern: decouple the view from the presenter

Tags: java, swing, design-patterns, guice, mvp

I'm writing an application in Swing and I'd like to make use of Model–view–presenter pattern. I found a sample application using this pattern and then I alter it to make use of Guice to do dependency injection. I was able to make it work with albeit with one problematic piece of code. Let me first show my code and later on the piece of code I find problematic.

`Application starting point`:

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor(onConstructor = @__(@Inject))
public class Main {

    private final View view;

    public static void main(final String[] args) {

        final Main main = Guice.createInjector().getInstance(Main.class);

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(main.view::createUI);
    }
}
```

`Model`:

```
public class Model {

    public String getPassword() {
        return "password";
    }
}
```

`Presenter`:

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor(onConstructor = @__(@Inject))
public class Presenter {

    private final View view;
    private final Model model;

    public void login(final String password) {

        final String result = model.getPassword().equals(password)
                ? "Correct password" : "Incorrect password";

        view.updateStatusLabel(result);
    }
}
```

Until this point everything seems to be fine.

The problem is in the `View` constructor. I manually create instance of `Presenter` using `this` (due to some coupling involved in MVP pattern) instead of letting `Guice` does it job.

**EDIT**

**How do I overcome this problem? As per comments,I find this code incorrect and I'd like to rewrite it so that the view could be injected into the presenter via dependency injection.**

`Guice` has this somewhat covered how to do this in  its documentation, however, I find it really difficult to understand the docs.

```
public class View {

    private final Presenter presenter;

    private JLabel statusLabel;
    private JTextField inputField;

    public View() {
        // manually adding this, should be DI
        this.presenter = new Presenter(this, new Model());
    }


    public void createUI() {
        // removed
    }

    //called by the presenter to update the status label
    public void updateStatusLabel(final String text) {
        statusLabel.setText(text);
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't make sense to me - isn't the view suppose to be de-coupled from the presenter?  If so, then creating the presenter inside the view seems like the wrong thing to do - shouldn't the presenter be either creating it or have it passed to it via dependency injection? Communication between the view and presenter should be handled via an observer pattern - please be kind, I only have a passing knowledge of MVP, as the last project I worked on that had was in the process of removing it due to code bloat

Comment: Generally, with Java Swing, you use a model-view-controller pattern.

Comment: I agree with @MadProgrammer, the view should be abstract and injected into the presenter via that abstraction. In my experience, that's usually an interface. This supports, what I believe to be, one of the key advantages of the pattern: testability.

Comment: @MadProgrammer In my question I tried to ask how do de-couple the view from the presenter. Please see my updated question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are indeed manually instantiating the `Presenter` in the `View` and you would ideally want this to be done by [Guice](https://github.com/google/guice) through dependency injection. That is a circular dependency issue because `Presenter` depends on `View` and... `View` depends on `Presenter`.

The simplest solution is to use a [method called 'injecting providers'](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/InjectingProviders). In Guice, providers are simple interfaces that provide instances of a type `T`. You can leverage this to decouple the view and presenter creation logic.

`View`: (using [provider binding](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/ProviderBindings))

```java
public class View {

    private final Provider<Presenter> presenterProvider;
    private Presenter presenter;

    private JLabel statusLabel;
    private JTextField inputField;

    @Inject
    public View(Provider<Presenter> presenterProvider) {
        this.presenterProvider = presenterProvider;
    }

    // Lazy initialization of Presenter.
    private Presenter getPresenter() {
        if (presenter == null) {
            presenter = presenterProvider.get();
        }
        return presenter;
    }

    public void createUI() {
        // Here you should use getPresenter() instead of presenter
        // removed
    }

    //called by the presenter to update the status label
    public void updateStatusLabel(final String text) {
        statusLabel.setText(text);
    }
}
```

`Presenter`:

```java
@RequiredArgsConstructor(onConstructor = @__(@Inject))
public class Presenter {

    private final View view;
    private final Model model;

    public void login(final String password) {

        final String result = model.getPassword().equals(password)
                ? "Correct password" : "Incorrect password";

        view.updateStatusLabel(result);
    }
}
```

Then you will need to bind these dependencies in Guice's module:

```java
public class ApplicationModule extends AbstractModule {
    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        bind(View.class).in(Singleton.class);
        bind(Presenter.class);
        bind(Model.class);
    }
}
```

And then finally, your `main` class should use this module:

```java
public class Main {

    private final View view;

    @Inject
    public Main(View view) {
        this.view = view;
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new ApplicationModule());
        final Main main = injector.getInstance(Main.class);

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(main.view::createUI);
    }
}
```

That setup will make sure that `Presenter` is injected into `View` lazily (on the first call of `getPresenter()`), breaking the circular dependency.

It uses [Just-In-Time Bindings](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/JustInTimeBindings): These are the bindings that you have not explicitly defined in your module, but Guice can still inject them because it knows how to build them.
When you are injecting `View` into `Main` and `Presenter` into `View` using a `Provider`, you are not creating explicit bindings for them in the `ApplicationModule`. But Guice can still make these injections because it can build `View` and `Presenter` using their injectable constructors (i.e., constructors that are annotated with `@Inject`), effectively performing just-in-time bindings.