# How do I update Swing component after GUI is initialised to avoid NPE in Java Swing?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, guice

While developing a Swing application I encounter a problem I cannot deal on my own. I'm trying to adhere to `Model-Viewer-Presenter` pattern. Please have in mind I may misread how to make use of this pattern, thought.  In the `Presenter` layer I'm reading file contents (I/O operation, quite long). As soon as the reading is done, I'd like to set the content of `JLabel` to what was read from the file. Seems to be easy. However, the code that reads the file contents is quite fast and it tries to set the content of JLabel field before the GUI is build and JLabel field in my class initialised.

```
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Presenter {

   private final View view;
   private final Model model;

   @Inject
   public Presenter(final View view, final Model model) {
      this.view = view;
      this.model = model;
      /**
       * In reality, I have here reading a file and invoking
       * view.updateStatusLabel() with its content.
       * The following code will produces NPE as view has not been initialized.
       * */
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> view.updateStatusLabel("test"));
   }

}
```

Here's `View` part where GUI is initialised:

```
public class View {

   private final Presenter presenter;

   private JLabel statusLabel;
   private JTextField inputField;

   public View() {
      this.presenter = new Presenter(this, new Model());
   }


   public void createUI() {
      this.statusLabel = new JLabel();
      // other GUI initilization
      // ...
   }
   //called by the presenter to update the status label
   public void updateStatusLabel(final String text) {
        statusLabel.setText(text);
   }
}
```

Application `main` method:

```
import com.google.inject.Guice;
import com.google.inject.Inject;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;

import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

@RequiredArgsConstructor(onConstructor = @__(@Inject))
public class Main {

   private final View view;

   public static void main(final String[] args) {

      final Main main = Guice.createInjector().getInstance(Main.class);

      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(main.view::createUI);
   }
}
```

if this is something important, I'm using `Guice` to have dependency injection covered. Even without `Guice` this problem would occurred. Here's my dependencies:

```
<guice.version>7.0.0</guice.version>
<dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.inject</groupId>
      <artifactId>guice</artifactId>
      <version>${guice.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.inject.extensions</groupId>
      <artifactId>guice-assistedinject</artifactId>
      <version>${guice.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
      <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
      <version>1.18.28</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

***EDIT***

Thanks to comment by @Gilbert Le Blanc I managed to rewrite the code to avoid NPE. Please see below updated code. I  removed dependency injection by `Guice` so that the code reads now (I hope so) easier. The code works as expected. However, as I am new to Swing I'd probably made some mistakes, hopefully someone points them so that they can be fixed.

Application starting point:

```
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Main {

   public static void main(final String[] args) {

      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new View()::createUI);
   }
}
```

Model:

```
    public class Model {
    
       private String password;
       private boolean initiliaized;

       // getters and setters here

       
    }
```

Interfaces needed for `Observer` design pattern:

```
interface Observer {
   void guiInitialized();
}

interface Subject {

   void registerObserver(Observer observer);

   void notifyObservers();
}
```

Presenter

```
public class Presenter implements Observer {

   private final View view;
   private final Model model;

   public Presenter(final View view, final Model model) {
      this.view = view;
      this.model = model;
      new Thread(() -> {
         try {
            Thread.sleep(5_000);
            model.setPassword("password");
            model.setInitiliaized(true);
         } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
         }
      }).start();
   }

   @Override
   public void guiInitialized() {
      // wait until gui is initialized
      new Thread(() -> {
         while ( !model.isInitiliaized() ) {
            try {
               Thread.sleep(500);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
               Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }
         }
         // GUI is initliazed by now
         view.updateStatusLabel("init");
      }).start();
   }

}
```

View

```
public class View {

   private final Presenter presenter;

   private final List<Observer> observers = new ArrayList<>();
   

   private JLabel statusLabel;
   private JTextField inputField;

   public View() {
      this.presenter = new Presenter(this, new Model());
   }

   @Override
   public void registerObserver(final Observer observer) {
      this.observers.add(observer);
   }

   @Override
   public void notifyObservers() {
      observers.forEach(Observer::guiInitialized);
   }


   public void createUI() {
      this.statusLabel = new JLabel();
      // other GUI initilization
      // ...

      registerObserver(presenter);

      notifyObservers();
   }

   //called by the presenter to update the status label
   public void updateStatusLabel(final String text) {
      statusLabel.setText(text);
   }
}
```

Comment: Isn't this the same as your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76700506/guice-and-mvp-pattern-decouple-the-view-from-the-presenter)?

Comment: @Abra My current questions is about avoiding NPE during initialisation.. How does these two questions look similar to you?

Comment: You read the file contents into the model and set a boolean when completed.  When you construct the GUI, you set the `JLabel` to " " (space).  When the GUI is completely created, you notify an observer.  Then and only then, depending on the boolean, you either update the `JLabel` text or wait for the file to be read completely.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc Could you have a look at my updated question, please?

Comment: I don't use lombok, so your code wouldn't even compile for me.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc  I removed Lombok dependency from the newly written code.